# How to test autocomplete android textview with espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a use case when I need to test a scenario which involve input text into autocomplete text view and select the item from drop down menu.

The code is to enter the value:

```
ViewInteraction appCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView = onView(
        allOf(withId(R.id.search_view), isDisplayed()));
appCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView.perform(click(), typeText("kits"), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

and input the data:

```
ViewInteraction appCompatTextView = onView(withText("kits"))
        .inRoot(
                RootMatchers.withDecorView(
                        not(mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())
                )
        ).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
appCompatTextView.perform(click());
```

The issue is when test script enters two first characters (I have a threshold on 2 chars) app shows the dialog but script can not finish enter others characters. So far I haven't found the root cause and the solution for it.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: "can not finish enter others characters." what do you mean? You're not actually typing "ts" in that snippet.

Comment: I mean when I enter the 'kits' keyword the test run only 'ki'

Comment: I update the code snippet. Thank you for point out on this!